# Instantiating objects in R - new vs structure

Tags: r, class, instantiation

I've seen classes in R instantiating using

```
x <- structure(1, class = "foo")
```

Source: https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/S3

and also

```
x <- new("foo", a = 1)
```

Which is more appropriate, using new or structure?

Comment: It depends on the class (S3 or S4) of the object you're trying to instantiate.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich That's the answer, so why not post it as such?

Comment: @DWin: I hoped the OP would clarify which types of objects they were using. As it currently stands, the question seems broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have known, Hadley had a section on his guide for S4 as well, where he says to instantiate using new

https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/S4